# firefox component doesn't seem to be loading

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, components

https://github.com/terrafrost/firefox-x-forwarded-for-spoofer

That's an addon I'm trying to revive that's not working in the latest version of Firefox and I'm trying to find out why.

Near as I can tell the component isn't working and I've no idea as to why.

I've tried making the chrome.manifest file read as follows:

```
content x-forwarded-for chrome/content/
overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul chrome://x-forwarded-for/content/overlay.xul
locale x-forwarded-for en-US chrome/locale/en-US/
component ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384 components/x-forwarded-for.js
contract @x-forwarded-for@frostjedi.com/x-forwarded-for.js;1 ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384
```

I've also tried @frostjedi.com/x-forwarded-for;1 (which is what x-forwarded-for.js has as the contract id but that didn't help) to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1942222 - works with firefox 15.0-16.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID you list in `chrome.manifest` should be the component ID, not the extension ID. Also, the contract ID seems to be incorrect, probably a copy&paste mistake. The correct lines would be:

```
component {f3bbf109-6d66-46ca-960e-4b78014023b3} components/x-forwarded-for.js
contract @frostjedi.com/x-forwarded-for;1 {f3bbf109-6d66-46ca-960e-4b78014023b3}
```

The component itself needs to be modified as well - to be compatible with Firefox 4 and above it should expose an `NSGetFactory` function instead of `NSGetModule`. It is highly recommendable to use [`XPCOMUtils.jsm` module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_code_modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm) for that, it will do most of the work for you. You can throw out the entire module definition and replace it by the following lines:

```js
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm");
var NSGetFactory = XPCOMUtils.generateNSGetFactory([XForwardedForProxy]);
```

Note that you no longer have to declare component ID and contract ID in the component itself, the entries in `chrome.manifest` are sufficient for Firefox 4 and above.

For reference: [XPCOM changes in Gecko 2.0](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM/XPCOM_changes_in_Gecko_2.0)